# What would be the best way to prevent certain file types attached to cases when received on Email-to-case?

Tags: case, files, email2case

What would be the best way to prevent certain file types attached to cases when received on Email-to-case?
Important to note that I would like the case record to be created successfully and files should not be created.

Thanks !

Comment: Not done it but first thought is an async job to temporarily reparent the file (for false positive review etc). But think about if/how to notify your users.

Comment: following on with @girbot -  trigger or after save Flow on `ContentDocumentLink` would be the place to do this